# Put color for raster data(aspect.tif) on QGIS1.8.0

Tags: qgis, raster, dem, color

I create aspect.tif from DEM file.
I could put the values(0 to 360)from contrast enhancement.

I could set color from color map(freakout or Pseudocolor).
In here, the data is shown by only 4 colors.
I could not change colors and add color type.

First of all, I could not select colormap tab.

My ideal color setting is 8 colors with 8 direction(0 to 45, 45 to 90, ....315 to 360)

Please tell me how to change color.

Answer (score 1):

If you select the color map option in the dropdown field, the color map tab will be activated and you can define any colors you want.

Here's the manual page related to rasters: http://docs.qgis.org/html/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/raster_properties.html

Comment: Dear underdark    Thank you for your quick response. This is big help for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you select 'Colormap' from the Colormap dropdown on the Style tab, then you can go to the Colormap tab and classify your data. *(This is counter-intuitive at best for native speakers, and probably totally senseless if English is your second language.)* For your classification scheme, you want to set it to 8 entries, then click Classify. However, if you want a separate category for flat ground (especially if you set flat ground to be -399 instead of zero), you'll need 9 entries. Set the colors to be whatever you want. Here's an example for a nine category scheme.

[image]